# View with Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to create a view from the following two tables:

```
Entry:
entry_id
entry_date
entry_amount
user_id

Forecast:
forecast_id
forecast_date
forecast_amount
user_id
```

Now I want to have a view which combines each entry with its forecast (same user_id and same date). This is fine, but I have a problem with those rows, which have a forecast and no entry, or vice versa.

I would like to still have all entries with no forecasts as well in the database. They should show up with a null values in the forecast fields. And the same for forecasts without entries.

Comment: Yes, full outer join is not supported in mysql till date check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (FULL OUTER JOIN) command is [not available on MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) you will need to use UNION to achieve this as given below

```
SELECT E.*, F.*
 FROM Entry E
 LEFT JOIN Forecast F ON E.user_id = F.user_id AND E.entry_date = F.forecast_date
UNION ALL
SELECT E.*, F.*
 FROM Forecast F 
 LEFT JOIN Entry E ON E.user_id = F.user_id AND E.entry_date = F.forecast_date
```

Comment: Thanks - interesting that mysql does not have FULL OUTER JOINs
works great

Comment: Using union removes duplicates. There might not be any in this case, but there isn't anything in the question that specifically excludes that. The solution to this is to use a union all instead, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

A full outer join would do that for you. You can simulate one with two outer joins and a union all:

```
select
   e.entry_id, e.entry_date, e.entry_amount, e.user_id,
   f.forecast_id, f.forecast_date, f.forecast_amount, f.user_id
from
   Entry e
   left outer join Forecast f on f.user_id = e.user_id and f.forecast_date = e.entry_date
union all
select
   e.entry_id, e.entry_date, e.entry_amount, e.user_id,
   f.forecast_id, f.forecast_date, f.forecast_amount, f.user_id
from
   Entry e
   right outer join Forecast f on f.user_id = e.user_id and f.forecast_date = e.entry_date
where
   e.entry_id is null
```

Comment: SELECT e.entry_id, 
 e.user_id, 
 e.entry__date, 
 e.entry_amount,
 f.user_id,
 f.forecast_period_end, 
 f.forecast_id, 
 f.forecast_amount
FROM Entry e FULL OUTER JOIN Forecast f ON e.user_id = f.user_id AND e.entry_date = f.forecast_period_end

Gives me an SQL error. I do not know why...

Comment: I changed the full outer join to a simulated full outer join. More info: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/